# Wrong USB flash mount options

Tags: mount, opensuse, vfat

openSuse mounts VFAT usb flash with `codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1` options which is wrong as I have Russian locale. How to set default mount options to `codepage=866,iocharset=cp1251`?